# A C++ iterator that adds an extra layer of indirection

Tags: c++, iterator

This iterator is designed with one purpose in mind. If before you had an iterator where you could do

```
int x = *it;
```

now you do

```
int x = **make_wrap_iterator(it);
```

This is useful for example if you want to use a range-based `for` loop to produce iterators to each element rather than values. You could do

```
std::vector<int> source = {1,2,3,4};
for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it :
    boost::make_iterator_range(
        make_wrap_iterator(source.begin()), 
        make_wrap_iterator(source.end())
    )
{
    std::out << *it << std::endl;;
}
```

Try it on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ef4j3T).

The implementation for `WrapIterator` is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

template <typename T>
struct WrapIterator : boost::iterator_facade
    < WrapIterator<T> ,T ,typename T::iterator_category ,T >
    {
        WrapIterator(T ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) {}
        T dereference() const { return m_ptr; }

        void increment() { m_ptr++; }
        void decrement() { m_ptr--; }
        void advance(int n){ m_ptr+=n; }
        typename T::difference_type distance_to
            (WrapIterator<T> const & other) const 
        {
            return other.m_ptr - m_ptr;
        }
        bool equal(WrapIterator<T> const & other) const {
            return other.m_ptr == m_ptr;
        }

    private:
        T m_ptr;
};

template <typename T>
WrapIterator<T> make_wrap_iterator(T it){return WrapIterator<T>(it);}
```

I have two questions.

1. `WrapIterator` is a terrible name. Is there a better name for this iterator? Boost already has a class called [`indirect_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/indirect.html) which does the exact opposite of my iterator in that if you do '`*it`' indirect iterator does '`**it`'. Essentially if you wrap my iterator with a boost `indirect_iterator` you get back the same thing you started with. I found this because I was going to call my class `indirect_iterator` and then was confused for a while until I realized that what I found in boost was the opposite of what I intended.
2. Is the class complete? Can it wrap any iterator type correctly?

Comment: Could you detail a bit more the purpose, what you gain by wrapping like this ?

Comment: I have a generic algorithm that stores copies of items from a range into a spatial 3d partition tree. It is useful to store the iterators to individual objects into the tree instead of copies of the objects themselves. Thus I can transform an iterator to some object into an iterator to an iterator to some object. In this case all I really need is a forward iterator

Comment: But if the iterator only goes one direction (as opposed to something like a 2D matrix for example where you could go vertically or horizontally), then you might as well just copy the iterators themselves ?

Comment: Copying the iterators is exactly what this is used for. If you have a generic algorithm that copies all the values between a beig and end iterator then the same algorithm will copy all the iterators if the begin and end are wrapped with the above tool.

Comment: I still don't understand why one would want to copy a whole range of iterators, whereas just a pair begin/end is enough to iterate.

Comment: Because I want to build a binary space partition tree that stores pointer/iterators to values rather than the values themselves. The constructor for the partition tree takes a pair of iterators

Comment: Worded like this, it still seems to me like you would want to store references, or some kind of pointers (smart or not) to values, rather than iterators, if the goal is just to avoid copying the values from somewhere else, where they are owned.

Comment: An iterator is exactly what I want to store.

Comment: So I wish to create a range that generates an iterator for every element. You will just have to accept that I have good reason for wanting this even if you do not understand it.

Comment: An iterator is better than a pointer. Imagine I have a linked list. If I just store the pointer to the values in the linked list then if I do ``std::next(ptr)`` I will get a pointer to some undefined piece of memory. If I have an iterator to my value in the linked list then I can do ``std::next(it)`` and get the next item in the list. Thus no I do not want to store references or pointers. I want iterators.

Comment: And the constructor for the binary tree is fixed. It stores values retrieved by iterating over a pair of iterators. So back to the code above. I create an iterator that when dereferenced returns an iterator and the tree stores that iterator as the value.

Comment: I think the idea is great, and could be very useful (in fact, I can think of a few cases where I could have used it), but unfortunately I can’t review this because it all really boils down to `boost::iterator_facade`, which I don’t know much about. I suspect that’s going to be true for most people, so you’re going to have a tough time finding a reviewer.